# How Do I make the href string value a format string in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a text view with

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

and string resource

```
<string name="link_text">This is a sample <a href="%1$s"></a> to create</string>
```

wanted to use something of this sort so i can set the link in code and still get 
it work using

```
getString(R.string.link_text, "https:google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use special escape chars :

```
<string name="link_text">This is a sample &#60;a href="%1$s"&#62;&#60;/a&#62; to create</string>
```

Here is a list (I'm not sure if it is complete):

```
"     (&#34; Or &quot;) 
'     (&#39; Or &apos;) 
&     (&#38; Or &amp;) 
lt(<) (&#60; Or &lt;) 
gt(>) (&#62; Or &gt;)
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem it shows the characteres in the text view... i want it to be able to how only the text between the a tag as id i set it in the string resource